# Why do nested tables change the scale of the page on mobile?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to create a HTML email (I know, I know) with nested tables. I've included
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
to set the appropriate page width and initial scaling on mobile. Before I add my nested table, everything looks correct, but once the table is nested, two things happen when viewed on mobile that I don't understand: 1) the entire page is zoomed in to desktop size, and 2) the content of the nested table is smaller than the content of the rest of the page. Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what I can do to avoid it?

Before the nested table is added (looks correct):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body style="background: #F0F2F2 url(https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/light-gray-geometric-pattern.png);">
        <center>
            <table style="background: #FFFFFF; max-width: 800px; border: 1px solid #DDD" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->

                    <td width="680">
                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; margin-top: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
                    </td>

                    <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->
                </tr>

                <tr> <!-- spacer row -->
                    <td><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="30"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#DDD" colspan="3">
                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.5; text-align: center;">Problems viewing this email? <a style="color:#13AAD9" href="#">View in browser</a></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table> <!-- end container table -->
            <br><br>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

After the nested table is added (broken):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body style="background: #F0F2F2 url(https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/light-gray-geometric-pattern.png);">
        <center>
            <table style="background: #FFFFFF; max-width: 800px; border: 1px solid #DDD" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">   <tr>
                <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->

                <td>
                    <table style="width: 680px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> <!-- START nested table -->
                        <tr>
                            <td width="250">
                                <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; margin-top: 0;">Foo</p>
                            </td>

                            <td width="250">
                                <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; margin-top: 0;">Bar</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table> <!-- END nested table -->
                </td>

                <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->

                <td width="680">
                    <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; margin-top: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
                </td>

                <td width="60" valign="top"><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="60"></td> <!-- spacer column -->
            </tr>

            <tr> <!-- spacer row -->
                <td><img src="https://thomasprintworks.com/temp/dynamic-letter1/clear.gif" width="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#DDD" colspan="3">
                    <p style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #414141; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.5; text-align: center;">Problems viewing this email? <a style="color:#13AAD9" href="#">View in browser</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> <!-- end container table -->
        <br><br>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `td width="680"` may have something to do with it. Try using percentages instead.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked!